# HTML File Input Angularjs Select same File only fires ones

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've made a Angular directive to warp the a file upload input.

```
directive('ngFile', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var button = element.find('button[data-fileInputButton]');
            var inputElement = element.find('input[type="file"]');        

            var updateModel = function (evt) {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.files = evt.target.files;
                    if (scope.startUpload) {
                        scope.startUpload();
                    }

                    evtl.target.files = [];
                });
            }

            inputElement.bind('change', updateModel);

            button.click(function () {
                var input = element.find('input[type="file"]');
                input.click();
            });
        }
    } 
});
```

When I click and select a file, everything is OK. However, when I select the file again, the event is not fired. It is only fired when I select another file. Why is this happening?

Comment: because the event is triggered when the input changes.

Answer (score 2):

The change is listening to the value and not to the files.

you need to do:

```
evt.target.value = "";
```

Good luck :)